# Do I need a transit visa or anything to visit the city while on a layover in Amsterdam? if am holding a Schengen visa

Tags: visas, schengen

I am travelling to Oslo (Norway) from Bahrain with a valid Schengen Visa and I have a stopover of 10 h 30 mins at Amsterdam Airport Schiphol, so will i be able to enter Amsterdam city from the airport?

I had mentioned first port of entry as Oslo (Norway) when I had applied for Schengen visa, so any additional formalities.

Comment: Yes, you are. You are able to enter the whole Schengen area with a Schengen visa.

Comment: Not only are you covered by your Schengen visa, you also have enough time, just remember to leave an hour for your return journey and two hours for the passport and security checks.

Comment: Thanks a lot, So there won't be any problem with the first port of entry? i have multi entry schengen visa & first time travelling to schengen area

Comment: No. The border guard might raise an eyebrow but if you explain the situation, everything should be fine. This happens all the time.

Comment: Oh that's great then,

Comment: my plan is to visit Amsterdam in transit & spend 1st 2 nights in Norway, then 7 nights in Iceland, so this plan will not be a problem? We have only German Embassy in Bahrain, so applied for Schengen via there mentioning Norway as first port of entry

Comment: AM an India national, so is there any changes in the rule?

Answer (score 2):

Given your itinerary, you will need to enter the Schengen area in Amsterdam no matter what (even if you had a very short layover and no intent to visit the city). Once you have done that, there is nothing physically stopping you from going to the city (there are one-way doors between the Schengen part of the airport and the luggage claim area and exits but no passport check).

Your visa almost certainly allows that (a regular Schengen visa does, as do various long-stay visas from Schengen member states). It's very common, I would not expect any problem, especially if you can show your tickets, etc. to explain why you have a Norwegian visa.

Even if you had an unusual visa (e.g. a so-called “limited territorial validity” visa), a transit visa would not help you.

Answer (score 0):

Is your visa only valid for Norway? Check the top of your visa stamp, and it should tell you if its valid for the entire Schengen area or just Norway.

If its valid for the entire Schengen area, then you can enter the city and roam around - you'll have to pass through immigration as the Netherlands would be your effective point of entry into Schengen.

Once you enter the Netherlands - your onward flight to Norway will be a domestic flight; so you don't have to worry about passport control/immigration.

Comment: Sorry for the delay... Yes it says for Schengen, not only for Norway, so hope there will not be any issues as you all advised.